# Saving SSID Data in SQLite Database Causes Force Close

Tags: java, android, sqlite, forceclose

I'm attempting to update my database with additional data (the users current SSID) however when attempting to save the database - the entire application force closes.

I understand there is a NullPointer exception is being caused when saving the data - but I have no idea what I've done wrong to cause it.

LOGCAT:

```
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at com.app.gamedemo.AddEditDevice.saveContact(AddEditDevice.java:117)
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at com.app.gamedemo.AddEditDevice.access$1(AddEditDevice.java:111)
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at com.app.gamedemo.AddEditDevice$1$1.doInBackground(AddEditDevice.java:83)
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-04 21:24:08.351: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    ... 4 more
```

SOURCE: (Updated w SCF's suggestion)

ADDEDITDEVICE.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class AddEditDevice extends Activity {

     private long rowID; 
     private EditText nameEt;
     private EditText capEt;
     private EditText codeEt;
     private TimePicker timeEt;
     private TextView ssidTextView;


      // @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
          setContentView(R.layout.add_country);
          WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
          String ssidString = info.getSSID();

          //TextView ssidTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiSSID);
          ssidTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiSSID);
          ssidTextView.setText(ssidString); 

          nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
          capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
          codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
          timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);






          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

          if (extras != null)
          {
             rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
             nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
             capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
             codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));    
             String time = extras.getString("time");
             String[] parts = time.split(":");
             timeEt.setCurrentHour(Integer.valueOf(parts[0]));
             timeEt.setCurrentMinute(Integer.valueOf(parts[1]));
             timeEt.setIs24HourView(false);


          }

          Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
          saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View v) 
              {
                 if (capEt.getText().length() != 0)
                 {
                    AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                       new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                       {
                          @Override
                          protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                          {
                             saveContact();
                             return null;
                          }

                          @Override
                          protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                          {
                             finish();
                          }
                       }; 

                    saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
                 }

                 else
                 {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditDevice.this);
                    alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                    alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                    alert.show();
                 }
              } 
         });}




           private void saveContact() 
           {
              DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

              if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
              {
                  dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                          capEt.getText().toString(),
                          timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":"
                              + timeEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                          codeEt.getText().toString(),
                       ssidTextView.getText().toString());

              }
              else
              {
                 dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                         nameEt.getText().toString(),
                            capEt.getText().toString(),
                              timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":"
                                  + timeEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                              codeEt.getText().toString(),
                              ssidTextView.getText().toString());
              }
           }
}
```

SOURCE:

DatabaseConnector.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


public class DatabaseConnector {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "WorldCountries";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

    public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
        dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }

       public void open() throws SQLException 
       {
          //open database in reading/writing mode
          database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       } 

       public void close() 
       {
          if (database != null)
             database.close();
       }       

       public void insertContact(String name, String cap, String code, String time, String ssid) 
               {
                  ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
                  newCon.put("name", name);
                  newCon.put("cap", cap);
                  newCon.put("time", time);
                  newCon.put("code", code);
                  newCon.put("ssid", ssid);

                  open();
                  database.insert("country", null, newCon);
                  close();
               }


               public void updateContact(long id, String name, String cap, String code, String time, String ssid) 
               {
                  ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
                  editCon.put("name", name);
                  editCon.put("cap", cap);
                  editCon.put("time", time);
                  editCon.put("code", code);
                  editCon.put("ssid", ssid);

                  open();
                  database.update("country", editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
                  close();
               }


               public Cursor getAllContacts() 
               {
                  return database.query("country", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, 
                     null, null, null, null, "name");
               }

               public Cursor getOneContact(long id) 
               {
                  return database.query("country", null, "_id=" + id, null, null, null, null);
               }

               public void deleteContact(long id) 
               {
                  open(); 
                  database.delete("country", "_id=" + id, null);
                  close();
               }
}
```

Comment: The NullPointerException is thrown before the attempt to store the data to the DB. You need to check what may be null in AddEditDevice.java:117, and maybe separate the variables and calls there (for debugging)

Comment: It is being caused when adding the line: ssid.getText().toString());

but I'm not sure how to correct the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you save the TextView into a local variable "ssidTextView", while you should save it to the field "ssid".
just change

```
TextView ssidTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiSSID);
```

into

```
ssid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiSSID);
```

Of course you will also have to rename "String ssid" into something else, say "ssidString".

Comment: I updated my source as you suggested - but now I'm getting two new errors: ssidString cannot be resolved to a variable and ssidTextView cannot be resolved

Comment: Add "String" in front of "ssidString".

Comment: Your original problem was that you gave two different variables the same name, "ssid". Refrain from that in the future and you will save yourself a lot of troubles.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! (That resolved 1/2 issues - but I'm still getting the "ssidTextView cannot be resolved" error)

Comment: Just above your "onCreate" you declared "private TextView ssid;". if you want to call your TextView by "ssidTextView" you should change this declaration accordingly.

Comment: I updated accordingly, and updated all references to "ssid" to ssidTextView but now I'm getting a new error stating "The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (TextView)"

Comment: Change
ssidTextView.setText(ssidTextView);            
to
ssidTextView.setText(ssidString);

Comment: Updated as suggested - now I'm back to having null pointer exceptions on lines 117, 111 and 83 (shown in updated logcat above)

Comment: Can you point out these lines? It's a bit difficult counting them here.

Comment: 117 =  dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
111 = private void saveContact() 
83 = saveContact();

Comment: Try adding this just before line 117 and post the line with this tag from the log after running it:
Log.i("Test for Null", ""+dbConnector+" "+nameEt+" "+capEt+" "+timeEt+" "+codeEt+" "+ssidTextView);
You'll have to import android.util.Log to run this line.

Comment: 04-04 22:10:32.451: I/Test for Null(14778): com.app.gamedemo.DatabaseConnector@430419a8 null android.widget.EditText{42ff5408 VFED..CL .F...... 7,79-793,132 #7f080005 app:id/capEdit} android.widget.TimePicker{43017128 V.E..... ........ 209,644-590,926 #7f08000c app:id/timeEdit} android.widget.EditText{4300f028 VFED..CL ........ 7,338-793,391 #7f080008 app:id/codeEdit} android.widget.TextView{42ff4e48 V.ED.... ........ 7,46-91,79 #7f080004 app:id/wifiSSID}

Comment: BTW - I REALLY appreciate your help with this!

Comment: You're welcome, though I think that this is as far as I can go... As it seems from this log your nameEt in null, meaning that findViewById can't find its ID "R.id.nameEdit" - which is odd.
I can't know why without seeing the entire project.
What I would do at this point is go to the layout file and try to delete this view and then add it again (with the Graphical Layout editing tool if possible) and then give it the same ID again.
One other thing is cleaning the project by Project->Clean...->Clean all projects -> OK and then try again.
If this doesn't help you can try posting the xml here.

Comment: I was missing the nameEt in my XML file - thank you (again) for all your (invaluable) help!